# Reading from a file and storing multiple arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, file

Having trouble reading from a file as a rows

```
 int status,i=0;
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("Accounts.txt","r+");
 do 
 {
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&ids[i]);
    status=fscanf(fp,"%lf",&balances[i]);
    fscanf(fp,"%ld",&phones[i]);
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&types[i]);
    i++;
 }
 while(status != -1 );
```

what happens is that the counter (i) gets incremented 3 times, which is odd... so thought of reading the arrays as different columns, but how to do that?
Edit: Here is the input data from the file
1150393
123412
12341
s

Comment: Please add indentation and the contents of the input file

Comment: use a single fscanf instead of multiple. Use printf to debug why and how i is incremented three time, from your code it look nearly impossible that it is being incremented three times.

Comment: It is not taking into account of line separator?

Comment: @Mazhar thanks for the reply! it works now

Comment: Great. Always post an understandable question to get quick help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/*Firstly the input file is not so clear to me what it contains. But still I think you need an answer like this:
you can use one fscanf() call instead of four like this :-
*/

```
do 
{
    status=fscanf(fp,"%d %lf %ld %c",&ids[i], &balances[i], &phones[i], &types[i]);
    i++;
}while(status != -1 );
```

Comment: ..though he should also check that `status == 4` so he knows that all the fields were assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The loop construct is flawed for what you are trying to accomplish.

Let's say the input file has only one line of data.

```
1001 1234.99 12345678 C
```

All the calls to `fscanf` succeed in the first iteration of the loop.
`i` is incremented. So its value is now `1`.

The first call to `fscanf` fails to read the data in the second iteration of the loop. The rest of the calls to `fscanf` fail to read the data too.
You increment `i` regardless of whether the calls to `fscanf` succeeded or not. Now, its value is `2`.

As a consequence, the value of `i` is `2` when you get out of the loop even though there is just one line of data.

You need to use something like:

```
// Read all the data corresponding to an index.
// If there is an error in reading all of them, break out of the loop.
while ( fscanf(fp, "%d %lf %ld %c", &ids[i], &balances[i], &phones[i], &types[i]) == 4)
{
   i++;
}
```